# Dataset interferes with SeedRandom

Tags: bugs, random, dataset

**Bug introduced in 11.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.1**

---

This seems like a pretty awful bug:

```
SeedRandom[1];
RandomInteger[10, 10]

Out: {1,4,0,7,0,0,8,6,0,4}
```

While:

```
SeedRandom[1];
Dataset[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>];
RandomInteger[10, 10]

Out: {7,0,0,8,6,0,4,1,8,5}
```

I see this with 11.0.1 on Linux, OS X, and Windows. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kuba, but then, those built-in symbols ought to have wrapped things in `BlockRandom[]` to prevent such interference.

Comment: @J.M. that would be nice indeed. So it is probably worth reporting but I must say I'm not surprised the result is different if dataset generation is put in between.

Comment: Identical results on `10.4`. So should this be marked a bug? It's not technically a bug. One can reasonable except `SeedRandom[]` to be used right before the appropriate function anyway.

Comment: My impression was that unless something explicitly calls a random number generator, the expected behavior is that the seed is unaltered. I don't think I've ever come across a non-random function that violates that expectation, except for `Dataset`.

Comment: Also re: using `SeedRandom` right before calling the random function, I don't think that's the only use case. For example I have a whole series of random calls that I'm making, and I usually just put a single `SeedRandom` at the very top to guarantee determinism. Having to place a `SeedRandom` in front of every random call seems rather ugly, and may actually result in worse randomization in some cases.

Comment: Agree it's a bug.  I bet that DataSet is using some random numbers under the hood to build a hash table.

Comment: I'd send it into tech support. Seems like a bug.

Comment: A (grotesque) workaround: `SeedRandom[1]; BlockRandom[Dataset[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>]]; RandomInteger[10, 10]`.

Comment: If it is an intended behaviour (and I can't see why it should be) it should at least be documented (e.g. in the "Possible Issues")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in **11.1**.

```
$Version
SeedRandom[1];
Dataset[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>];
RandomInteger[10, 10]
```

> 11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)
>
> {1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 4}